# How to use crontab for sending weekly email in php?

Tags: php, cron

i am new to php... and i dont know how to use crontab widget..can anybody explain me...how to send weekly emails...

Comment: Crontab *widget*?! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 3):

This will run a job weekly:

```
0 0 * * 0 /path/to/php yourscript.php
```

[Nice intro](http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html) to cron and crontab.

Answer (score 0):

TO your problem there is 2 step solution

1. Create cron tab using `crontab -e` command, add a following line to your cron: `0 0 * * 0 php your/php/script/path/email_script.php`
2. Create a Email script and write yor email functions here.
   Note: If you are including a file in your script make sure that you give full path "/var/www/"